# Google Play Store - Can't search by app name

Tags: google-play

I have just published my app to Google Play Store but I couldn't seem to search for it in the store and it will only appear when I search by developer name. Every time I search by the name, other apps with similar name tend to appear and my app won't even appear at the bottom. Why wouldn't it even appear at the bottom and how can I make it show?

Answer (score 1):

It can sometimes take a little while for Google's app search index to update, especially for new apps. Give it a few days, if it still doesn't appear contact Google Play developer support.

Comment: I see, thanks. I shall wait for a couple of days and see.

Comment: Did your app shows on Google play store or not after waiting for a couple of days .